# Can't append elements to html with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add all destinations as headers in my div but only the last one is added. What's wrong with this code?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {

            var $dialog = $("#dialog");

            var data = {
                destinations: [
                    {dep: "Varna Airport", dest: "Domodedovo Airport"},
                    {dep: "Domodedovo Airport", dest: "Schwechat"},
                    {dep: "Schwechat", dest: "Heathrow Airport"}
                ]
            };

            $.each(data.destinations, function(key, destination) {

                var $title = $('h1').text(destination.dep + ' - ' + destination.dest);
                $dialog.append($title);
            });
        });

    </script>

 <div id="dialog"></div>
```

Comment: why not `var $title = "<h1>"+ destination.dep + " - " + destination.dest + "</h1>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use:

```
var $title = $('<h1 />').text(destination.dep + ' - ' + destination.dest);
```

Why?

`$('h1')` was setting the contents of the first `h1` tag it could find to the current string, then moving that `h1` to `$dialog`.
`$('<h1 />')` will actually create a new `h1` for each iteration, which is what you need here.

Answer (score 5):

You need to create `h1` using jQuery, currently you are selecting `h1`.

Use

```
$('<h1></h1>')
```

or

```
$('<h1/>')
```

instead of

```
$('h1')
```

```js
$(function() {

  var $dialog = $("#dialog");

  var data = {
    destinations: [{
      dep: "Varna Airport",
      dest: "Domodedovo Airport"
    }, {
      dep: "Domodedovo Airport",
      dest: "Schwechat"
    }, {
      dep: "Schwechat",
      dest: "Heathrow Airport"
    }]
  };

  $.each(data.destinations, function(key, destination) {

    var $title = $('<h1></h1>').text(destination.dep + ' - ' + destination.dest);
    $dialog.append($title);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

Comment: This is how every answer should be!

Comment: Indeed, by using $('h1') you're refering to a selector, hence the last one being the only visible. $('<h1></h1>') creates an element instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {

        var $dialog = $("#dialog");

        var data = {
            destinations: [
                {dep: "Varna Airport", dest: "Domodedovo Airport"},
                {dep: "Domodedovo Airport", dest: "Schwechat"},
                {dep: "Schwechat", dest: "Heathrow Airport"}
            ]
        };
       var $title = "";
        $.each(data.destinations, function(key, destination) {
              //Edited
            $title += $('<h1 />').text(destination.dep + ' - ' + destination.dest);

        });
        $dialog.append($title);
    });

</script>
```

Comment: The issue will remain as long as $title calls for $('h1') instead of creating a new element.